# mathematic induction, how to prove that this work in this recursive function

Tags: algorithm

i'm reading this book: [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848000693), and i'm having a problem to understand, it's about inductive assumption, so i've this pseudocode:

```
Increment(y)
  if y = 0 
    then return(1) 
 else if (y mod 2) = 1 
   then return(2 · Increment(⌊y/2⌋))
  else 
    return(y + 1)
```

So i've to prove through mathematic induction that this code really work, the first part is easy:

```
if y = 0 
    then return(1)
```

The last part is easy too, it's get even number

```
else 
    return(y + 1)
```

But middle part being very difficult for me:

```
else if (y mod 2) = 1 
   then return(2 · Increment(⌊y/2⌋))
```

here is the explanation of the book:

```
Now, the case of odd y (i.e. y = 2m + 1 for some integer m) can be dealt with as:
(y = 2m + 1; because 2m + 1 is equal to any odd number)//this is what i understand

= 2 · Increment(⌊(2m + 1)/2⌋)//(2m + 1)/2 = m + 1/2
= 2 · Increment(⌊m + 1/2⌋)//ok we get here, but how (m + 1/2) will be the "m" bellow?
= 2 · Increment(m)
= 2(m+1)
= 2m+2 =y+1
```

Anyone could explain how to prove that this recursive really work? And how prove this by mathematic induction.

Comment: Whether it "works" or not depends on what it is intended to do.

Comment: increment, if you give 1, the function will return 2 and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> = 2 · Increment(⌊m + 1/2⌋) //ok we get here, but how (m + 1/2) will be the "m" bellow?

Because `⌊m + 1/2⌋ = m`, that's as simple as that. (I'm assuming you know that `⌊m + 1/2⌋` means `floor(m + 1/2)`.

Note that `m` is an integer, and given that `1/2` is fractional, then `floor(m+1/2)` is `m`. In fact, `floor(m + x)`, where `0 <= x < 1`, is just `m`: adding any fractional part to `m` does not change the result of `floor()`.

So you get `2 * Increment(m) = 2(m+1) = 2m+2 = (2m+1)+1 = y+1`

**UPDATE:** Proof by induction is pretty similar.

Recall the general layout of proof by induction: first, we elaborate the induction hypothesis. Then, we show that this hypothesis holds for a base case (usually, a base case is when n = 0, or n = 1). Last, but not least, we show, using the hypothesis, that if it works for some value of `n`, then it also works for `n+1`. Since the hypothesis works for the base case, and because we showed (with an **induction step**) that if it works for `n`, then it works for `n+1`, then it must be true for every value greater than or equal to the base case value.

**Hypothesis**

In this specific case, our hypothesis is that this function:

```
I(n) = 1 if n is 0
       n+1 if n is even
       2 * I(floor(n / 2)) otherwise
```

is equal to `n+1`, that is,

`I(n) = n+1`

Where `I(n)` is just a short hand notation for `Increment(n)`. You can also see the hypothesis as a set of 3 mathematical statements (in other words, the hypothesis is that each of the three cases evaluates to `n+1` in the conditions stated).

**Base case**

The base case is when `n = 0`. For `n = 0`, `I(n)` evaluates to `1`, which is `n+1` (with `n` being 0), so we have proven that the hypothesis works for `n = 0`.

Now, we want to prove that if our hypothesis works for `n`, then it works for `n+1`.

**Induction step**

If `I(n) = n+1` holds, then `I(n+1) = (n+1)+1` must be true. Basically, we are saying, "OK, if `I(n)` evaluates to its argument plus one, then it means that `I(n+1)` must be `(n+1)+1`. This is what we have to prove: we must show that `I(n+1) = (n+1)+1`.

Now, according to the original definition for `I(n)`, we have two cases: either its argument is even, or it is odd.

This time, the argument to the function `I` is `n+1` - let's consider both cases.

If `n+1` is even, by the definition of `I(n)`, we can immediately see that `I(n+1) = (n+1)+1`.

If `n+1` is odd, then we know that `n+1 = 2m+1` for some integer `m`, because if `n+1` is odd, then `n` is even, which means that there is an integer `m` less than `n` such that `2m = n`. So, we can rewrite `n+1` as `2m+1`:

```
I(n+1) = I(2m + 1) = 
       = 2 * I(floor((2m+1) / 2)) =
       = 2 * I(floor(m + (1/2)) =
       = 2 * I(floor(m)) = // we can remove 1/2 for the same reason
       = 2 * I(m) =
       = 2 * (m+1) = // inductive step; we used the hypothesis that I(n) = n+1
       = 2*m + 2 = 
       = (2*m+1) + 1 =
       = (n+1) + 1
```

This shows that if the proposition is true for `floor(n/2)` (because `m` is `n/2`), then it is also true for `n+1`. By using [strong induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction), we can prove that if the proposition is true for all m, 0 <= m <=n, it is also true for n+1 (see comment below).

So, indeed, `I(n+1) = (n+1)+1` for any integer, **assuming that** `I(n) = n+1` **is valid**.

We showed that the hypothesis works for `n+1` if it works for `n`, and we showed that it works for `n = 0`. Thus, it works for `n >= 0`.

Comment: thanks Filipe, i passed the day trying to prove it only in mathematic and i forgot about the code, this is why my number never was matched.

Comment: ok, i proved it by the code, but how would i prove it by mathematic induction?

Comment: that's the major problem

Comment: In the odd number case, you actually proved that if the proposition is true for floor(n/2) it is true for n+1. To use that properly, you need [strong induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction), in which you prove that if the proposition is true for all m, 0 <= m <=n, it is also true for n+1.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I had a bit of a feeling that the proof for the odd case was still missing something. Thanks for your contribution, I'm updating my answer with this information.

Comment: Skienna doesn't explain that `floor(x) = ⌊x⌋` in his text. As a matter of fact I mistook those symbols for square brackets at first. While it may be reasonable to assume that knowledge for this text, I certainly did not know it. Knowing that makes much clearer what he's doing. Also this wikipedia entry helped: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: @orangepips made the exact same assumption! thanks for adding this comment, hadn't come across that notation before!

Comment: Great answer, +1, I felt Skienna jumped a moved a bit fast through the question but I get it now :)

Comment: This makes so much sense now, thank you Filipe for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

`but how (m + 1/2) will be the "m" bellow?`

`1/2` leads to a quotient `0` in `C`